# How to return keys which are not in a list?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, notin

I have the following dict:

```
d = {'Z':1,'A':2,'C':3}
```

I want to return all the keys that are not in `['A','B']`

I know that `[k for k in d.keys() if 'A' not in k]` works but `[k for k in d.keys() if ['A','B'] not in k]` doesn't because `not in` expects a string and not a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to iterate, you can use the set difference operation.

```
>>> d = {'Z':1,'A':2,'C':3}
>>> l = ['A','B']
>>> set(d) - set(l)
{'Z', 'C'}
```

Comment: Or `d.keys() - set(l)`

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you are asking for:

```
# Check for exact key match
d = {'Z':1,'A':2,'C':3}
[k for k in d.keys() if k not in ['A', 'B']]

# Substring match
d = {'Z':1,'A':2,'C':3}
[k for k in d.keys() if not any(s in k for s in ['A', 'B'])]
```